# How Keep website session in android webview

Tags: php, android, mysql, session, webview

I'm new to android developing. I just create an android app for my website using android webview. when i open my website from mobile browser first time it ask login details and once i logged in and close the browser without deleting cookies , then i open the browser again and visit my website it does not ask login again.

But when I open my website from my webview app first time it ask login, when i logged in and close the webview app, and once again I open the app it ask me to login again. it ask me to login whenever i open this webview app. i want to maintain my website session like web browsers, how can i achieve this in android webview?

my website has php, mysql login system.

I just want to create an app like mobile browser

my android code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    mywebview.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com/");


          }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep session open from Android app to website in a webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543352/keep-session-open-from-android-app-to-website-in-a-webview)

Comment: Probably you need to send credentials in each new request from web view

Comment: I'm not sending credentials in each new request from browser,  but that was worked

Comment: No, both are not similar @rahul

Comment: Do you have did it yet? I have same problem. Please share your solution! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOM Storage API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setDomStorageEnabled(boolean)), to enable API add this line before loading url:

```
mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do to help maintain a user's session? I tried this but nothing changed. Upon force closing the app and reopening it the webview asks me to log in again. It seems like setting `webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK` seems to work, but then I am unable to log out of the app...

Answer (score -6):

I was having the same issue and I solved it by enabling cache for the App. I think it might be solved if you add the following to the code you posted:

```
 //enable in-app cache
 mywebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Hope this works for you too.

Good luck!

Comment: Changed nothing n my case.